# Ubuntu on external USB Hard Drive

Tags: usb, 13.10, hard-drive

I just wanted to ask, before I do it. I copied my entire system with an exception of few not needed folders to an external USB HDD. If I install Ubuntu (same version) on it, will it work as it is now? Will I lose any data? I'm sorry if it's a duplicate, but I could not find an answer for it. If anyone tried it, please let me know what happens exactly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to install grub to the USB to boot from it.  You can try it out before doing that by running

```
sudo update-grub
```

and the new USB system should be found and added to the grub menu.  Try it out.  If you want to boot from the USB, run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
```

where x is your actual device, and change the BIOS boot order to boot from USB before the hard disk..

Comment: Eh, what if the system I copied was encrypted (I rsync'd it to external)? Will it boot? I have an idea to split the external to 2 partitions, and install on empty one, and copy the data later.